# Would you please undelete this question

Tags: discussion

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9549/is-it-really-god-behind-the-facebook-page#comment38548_9549

Let it hang around for 1 day. What I want is proof that the guy behind the facebook is not God. It's really simple. The technique used to proof that it's wrong can be useful to understand all other God's claim.

Or maybe we can't really proof it? I mean? What? sceptics just claim that it's not God and close questions? No wonder religious people don't appreciate atheism. You got to give some explanation folks.

Actually I do have doubt. Yea if I look deeper I am sure I can find proof, like misspelling and stuffs (real God doesn't make mistake). But how do we know?

Comment: I think jim thio is trolling us.

Comment: You should turn that into a question. C'mon, I am seriously seeking God here. The most important skill would be to differentiate bogus claims than something else that are worthy of further investigation. Where else should I ask that beside in sceptic forum? So that's how sceptic think right? It's obviously false and somebody asking it are called trolling. What about if it's true? I mean it's not less credible than other religious claims. You mean an omniscience God won't know that weed is harmless? Well there are religions that believe otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, religion is off topic in Skeptics. And second of all, there’s a reason for that.

> The technique used to proof that it's wrong can be useful to understand all other God's claim. [sic]

No it cannot. You can just make a claim that is in principle not investigable. See  Sagan’s [*The Dragon in My Garage*](http://godlessgeeks.com/LINKS/Dragon.htm).

> What I want is proof that the guy behind the facebook is not God.

Why? “I want proof” is not a skeptical approach. The burden of proof is on this guy, not on the rest of us.

Furthermore, how is that even an interesting question? Is there a single person *seriously* claiming that this is god? What reason is there to assume that this is anything other than a joke?

Comment: If we ignore the number of believers, what reason there is to assume that Torah, Quran, Gospels, are all not man made? I think we got something interesting here. Believers count. That's the main variable isn't it?

Comment: @Jim Nobody believes in the Facebook page though. As for your point about Torah etc.: spot on. Those are of course also made up.

Comment: Can't we say something? Anything.... The joke is too funny. There are mistakes. I mean what? Religion is too holy we just give up agree and to disagree? An atheist were sent to jail in my country. There are hordes of muslims believing that my country will be richer under shariah. I guess sceptics avoid politically significant questions but that's precisely the MOST important one especially if the answer is politically incorrect. Don't you think? Don't you want this forum filled with visitors? Start having questions that interest them.

Comment: Religion isn't too holy. Religion is too boring. It doesn't lead to interesting factual debates.